# Is R logger's debugger level - FINEST equal to Python's DEBUG?

Tags: python, r, debugging, logging, log-level

I'm trying to convert an **R** script to **Python** by understanding its functionality.

They've created a **logger in R** and set the level for the **logger**. What I'm confused about it is the word `FINEST` as log level. I haven't come across any such level before in any language.

Is that `FINEST` level in **R** equals to **Python's** `DEBUG`, which gives all the output?

```
setLevel(level='FINEST', container=r_logger)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The finest/finer/fine levels of the R logging package don't exist in python. With [`loglevels`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logging/logging.pdf) you can see the individual levels and their numeric value. This tells you that they are supposed to be even below `DEBUG`. If you definitely must have them in python it's possible to create [custom levels](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#custom-levels).

R logging package levels:

```
  NOTSET   FINEST    FINER     FINE    DEBUG     INFO  WARNING     WARN 
       0        1        4        7       10       20       30       30 
   ERROR CRITICAL    FATAL 
      40       50       50
```

Python log levels:

```
{50: 'CRITICAL', 40: 'ERROR', 30: 'WARNING', 20: 'INFO', 10: 'DEBUG', 0: 'NOTSET'}
```

Comment: I passed `1` instead of `logging.DEBUG` to Python logger and it is working.